# What is the best solution for Windows in the cloud?

Tags: windows, cloud-computing, cloud

Best can be cheapest or most up to date.  I'm more interested in cheapest.
Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying do, get RDP Access to the server, host an ASP.NET web application, etc?  More info is needed.

Comment: I'm trying to create a 2010 Team Foundation Server with SQL Server Enterprise 2008 R2 and MOSS 2010.  This requires at least 2GB of RAM and 2 cores.  I would like to connect to it remotely from http and rdp into it also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Rackspace](http://www.rackspace.com/index.php) is another cloud provider that support windows

Answer (score 0):

Would you settle for *biggest* over "cheapest or up to date"?

> [Windows Azure Platform](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/windowsazure)
>
> [Amazon EC2 Running Microsoft Windows Server & SQL Server](http://aws.amazon.com/windows/)